# Rhostudio path Eclipse Mac Lion 10.7.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rhomobile, rhodes

I have a problem with Rhostudio, Mac OS X 10.7.3 Lion and Ecplise.
Rhostudio install as app as a plugin but it does not work.
If I create the project is blank. In the preferences tells me can not find the path of Rhodes.

On my Mac development in Ruby on Rails with Aptana Studio 3. It works perfectly and use Ruby 1.9.3 and RVM.

The gems are installed correctly.

What is my problem? What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on Mac OS X Lion 10.7.3; the project is blank because Rhostudio is not properly installed, the installation seems to had gone through but it failed.

I followed the instructions from here http://docs.rhomobile.com/rhostudio.tutorial#installing-rhostudio but when I ran the install gems script, a 'Please install building tools' message was coming out on the terminal. The script fails because it looks for the developer folder and does not find it, you can still run Rhostudio, but it doesn’t work properly. There are several things you could do, like installing a version of Xcode that would create the developer folder, but you don’t really need that.

This is what I did:
1. I cleaned all previous installations of Rhostudio.

1. I installed the latest Xcode, the latest version of Xcode does not create the developer folder, as you can see here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/Articles/xcode_4_3.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/1006-SW1
2. I then installed the Command-Line Tools; these are now optional and the instructions are on the same link of step two.
3. I repeated the basic installation steps from the tutorial and when it was time to run the install gems script I opened it with a text editor and ran every command manually from the command line, I skipped the validations that search for the developer folder and the Java installation. The developer folder doesn’t have to be there anymore but you must have Java installed.
4. Once I finished running every command the installation was complete. If you create a new project this time the folder should not be empty.
5. I configured Rhostudio according to the instructions and the framework I needed to work on and everything went smooth.

I hope that helps, and note that whenever you tried installing by running the Install Gems script the error was coming out to the terminal, based on that message you’ll find if something else is happening. The two initial validations can only output the error messages 'Please install building tools' or 'Please install java development kit'.